# Why can Kingpin get Punisher released from prison, but not himself?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

Kingpin tells the guards to release Punisher, why doesn't he simply tell them to release him instead? He says something about playing the "long game", what could be meant by this?

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but I'm guessing Kingpin WANTS to stay in jail, where he appears to be "harmless" to his enemies.  Clearly, the fact that he can just tell the guards to release someone proves that he is not, but his enemies probably don't know how much control he really has.

Comment: Plausible deniability. Fisk can get out sooner if he's not caught actively committing crimes in prison.

Comment: If he escapes, he will be a wanted criminal and the entire police force will be looking for him. He wants to be released when his sentence is up, while in the meantime Punisher eliminates any competition.

Comment: @Dennis_E - you should post that as an answer, it's what I was going to do until I saw you had already posted it as a comment.

Comment: @sirjonsnow I thought it was too short to be an answer, but I've posted it. Thnx

Answer (score 6):

The way I understood it, Fisk wants to sit out his sentence. If he escapes, he will be a fugitive and the entire police force will be looking for him.

He intends for the Punisher to eliminate any competition, so that when he is finally released, he can "take over".